# Unity Map generation and colors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently following a Brackeys tutorial on procedural terrain generation colors. I got to a point where it gives me this error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. mapgeneration.CreateShape () (at Assets/mapgeneration.cs:108
> mapgeneration.Update () (at Assets/mapgeneration.cs:131)

I am using gradients to display color on line 108 in CreateShape. This is the line:

```
colors[iloopedforvertecy] = gradient.Evaluate(height);
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class mapgeneration : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    Mesh mesh;
    Color[] colors;
     
    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    public int xsize = 20;
    public int zsize = 20;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public float smooth = 1.0f;
    public MeshCollider _mesh;

    public Transform water;
    public float scale;
    public float smoothfactor;
    
    public float xoffset = 0.0f;
    public float zoffset = 0.0f;

    public float minwaterheight;
    public float maxwaterheight;

    public float minterainheight;
    public float maxterainheight;
    public Gradient gradient;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       mesh = new Mesh();
       GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    
       CreateShape();
       _mesh = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
      
       water.transform.position = new Vector3(0, Random.Range(minwaterheight, maxwaterheight), 0);
    }
    
    void CreateShape()
    {
        vertices = new Vector3[(xsize + 1) * (zsize + 1)];
        water.transform.localScale = new Vector3(xsize, 0, zsize);
        int iloopedforvertecy = 0;
    
        triangles = new int[xsize * zsize * 6];
        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;
    
        for(int z = 0; z < zsize; z++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xsize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xsize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xsize + 2;
    
                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }  
            vert++;
        }
    
        colors = new Color[vertices.Length];
    
        for (int z = 0; z <= zsize; z++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x <= xsize; x++)
            {
                float xCoord = (float)x / xsize * scale + xoffset;
                float zCoord = (float)z / zsize * scale + zoffset;
             
                float y =  Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord * smooth, zCoord * smooth) * smoothfactor;
               
                vertices[iloopedforvertecy] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                iloopedforvertecy += 1;

                if(y > maxterainheight)
                {
                    maxterainheight = y;
                }
    
                if(y < minterainheight)
                {
                    minterainheight = y;
                }
    
                float height = Mathf.InverseLerp(minterainheight, maxterainheight, 0.5f); //vertices[iloopedforvertecy].z
                Debug.LogWarning(height);
                colors[iloopedforvertecy] = gradient.Evaluate(height);
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateMsh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        
        mesh.colors = colors;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CreateShape();
        UpdateMsh();
    } 
}
```

I know that my code is messy. Still new to coding and unity in general.

Oh PS. Can somebody please help me add a collider to code generated object as you can see in the code above?

Comment: And which line is it erroring on. What values do the variables at that line have?

Comment: it is erroring on line 108. The code is in the Createshape loop.  This is the code "colors[iloopedforvertecy] = gradient.Evaluate(height);"

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If yes, you might press at the start of line and it will Add breakpoint (red point to that line), everytime you will execute this piece of code, it will stop and you are able to see current values in realtime. F5 will continue with running the code. This way you can check what is inside, how big is the array and why you are getting out of the size of the array.

Comment: Im guessing if you debugged the value of iloopforvertecty its 1 to big as you increment it then use it in colours it could be the last one of the loop trying to set 1 more than you have

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop you increase the value of `iloopedforvertecy` before you evaluate your gradient value.
Because of this the last value of `iloopedforvertecy` will be greater than the array length of your colors array.

Try to move the line which increases the value at the end of the loop

```
for(int x = 0; x <= xsize; x++)
{
    float xCoord = (float)x / xsize * scale + xoffset;
    float zCoord = (float)z / zsize * scale + zoffset;
             
    float y =  Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord * smooth, zCoord * smooth) * smoothfactor;
               
    vertices[iloopedforvertecy] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    // iloopedforvertecy += 1; // HERE THE VALUE WAS INCREASED

    if(y > maxterainheight)
    {
        maxterainheight = y;
    }
    
    if(y < minterainheight)
    {
        minterainheight = y;
    }
    
    float height = Mathf.InverseLerp(minterainheight, maxterainheight, 0.5f); //vertices[iloopedforvertecy].z
    Debug.LogWarning(height);
    colors[iloopedforvertecy] = gradient.Evaluate(height);
    iloopedforvertecy += 1; // HERE SHOULD THE VALUE BE INCREASED

}
```

In the example here I commented the two lines.